# joomla this->countModules странно работает

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Есть модуль, который отображает последние добавленные товары. Возникла потребность запилить модуль, который отображает только товары, которые есть на складе. 
 Я взял модуль с добавленными товарами, скопировал, подправил запрос в БД, чтобы вытаскивались только товары, которые есть на складе, переименовал, установил  через менеджер плагинов\модулей и повешал на главное меню сайта в менеджере меню, в точности так-же как был повешан модуль отображения последних добавленных итемов.
Т.е. все установки 1 в 1, модули 1 в 1, за исключением запроса к бд и названия

Что не работает: 
После того, как был добавлен новый модуль и прикреплен к менюшке - новый модуль заработал как полагается. Т.е. отображаются в  Left все менюшки, хедер, футер, все ок. НО отвалился оригинальный модуль, с которого копировался новый. А конкретно отвалилось отображение итемов позиции LEFT.
Дебагером, в index.php шаблона страницы, в $showLeftColumn = ($this->countModules('left'));  showLeftColumn = 4 в новом модуле, и showLeftColumn = 0 в старом модуле.
[image: Вот]

Если необходимо - скину настройки модулей. Но они идентичные. Код идентичен, поменяны названия в XMLках и самом php файле и добавлено пару строк SQL кода. Больше ничего не менялоьс. 
Установка соответвенно через менеджер расширений - установка

Вопрос: 
Как так? :)

J 1.5.25 + VirtueMart

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого воспользуйтесь ссылкой [edit], расположенной под метками.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что модуль был просто не опубликован :) My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно-было проверить позицию вывода модуля и что модуль-таки опубликован.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сделали копию модуля, сделали правку выборки и хотите, чтобы работал исходный модуль тоже? Для этого нужно еще изменить имя модуля, чтобы оно отличалось от оригинального, с соответствующими правками в самом модуле.

Например, для переименования модуля mod_modulename в mod_modulename1 необходимо переименовать основную папку модуля, файлы модуля mod_modulename.php, mod_modulename.xml в mod_modulename1.php, mod_modulename1.xml. Внести замену mod_modulename на mod_modulename1 в этих файлах. Внести замену имен констант в языковых файлах (MOD_MODULENAME_* на MOD_MODULENAME1_*) и во всех файлах константы также изменить.